# How to get the application id from inside a library using my project?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle, android-library

How can I get the application ID from the application using my library using gradle?

Or any way to put it inside a xml file.

Comment: Call `getPackageName()` on a `Context` supplied to your library.

Comment: I need to set it in my res/xml/authenticator.xml -> accountType. So I think I can't get it this way, unless I could find a way to configure the authenticator at runtime

Comment: I don't know of a way for you to modify a XML resource at compile time like that, other than by some custom Gradle task.

Comment: That's what I am trying to do now using Gradle. Is there a way to get the application Id from the app using my library?

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the custom Gradle task would be in the app, and the app would have its own `res/xml/authenticator.xml`, overriding anything you ship with your library. The application ID is only known at the time of compiling the app.

Answer (score 7):

You want to get Your App id that defined in gradle then it is

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID
```

or You can get it

```
Context.getPackageName()
```

Comment: package name and application id can be different so, should only use BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID

Answer (score 5):

Only Android application project can contain the `applicationId` property in app `build.gradle` file.

Android Library project **must not** contain the `applicationId` property in app `build.gradle` file. so there is no way to retrieve the application id from the library.